# Can't login in Magento 1.6.2 admin panel through the newest firefox and chrome (IE is fine)

Tags: admin-panel, magento-1.6

can't login in admin panel by Firefox Ver. 52.0.2 or Google Chrom Version 57.0.2987.133 but the oldest version of both are working. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check database..Go to the table 'core_config_data'..Replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' in both secure and unsecure base URLs..Restart the server and try..

Comment: Not working. Anyway thank you. I will try to clear cache again and see.

Answer (score 0):

Please Clear your browser cache and cookies. Also please check for magento cache and session folders to make these empty to get login work.

Please try and let me know the progress.

Comment: I did but still not working on firefox